# what is the function of pre-emphasizer and dee-emphasizer in Stereophonic FM Receiver?

Tags: communication, digital-communications, frequency-modulation, stereo

what is the purpose of theses two block ?

I know that pre-emphasizer will  boost the high frequencies before transmission and dee-emphasizer will reducing them by a corresponding amount in the receiver

But is it important in the Stereophonic FM Receiver ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Googling "fm pre emphasis", I found any number of sites that explain this adequately.  For example, [Pre-emphasis (FM) explained](http://claessonedwards.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=72&Itemid=89)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The de-emphasis is used to flatten the noise acquired during transmission. White noise in the RF input of the receiver does not come out of the FM demodulator as white noise. The de-emphasis filter is designed to flatten this noise spectrum and turn it in to white noise.  However, it also affects the signal itself, so the emphasis filter is required to get a flat signal with the de-emphasis.

Comment: This isn't quite correct.  Pre-emphasis is used to boost the high-frequency content in the original signal so as to improve the overall signal-to-noise ratio.  The matching de-emphasis in the receiver restores the signal to its original response.

Comment: That's exactly what I said.  The point is that the receiver is what generates the non-white noise spectrum, so the de-emphasis filter is designed to whiten that and then the pre-emphasis filter is designed to match the de-emphasis filter so the signal is not distorted.